# IBM Maximo App duplicate columns read-only

Tags: edit, maximo

I have duplicated one of IBM Maximo application and need to edit some field names in new application's tables, but these tables are `read-only`.

In XML theses `tables`, which fields I need to edit, are with `id included` 
How and where I can edit them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague, not stating which application you cloned or which table in that application is read-only. But here are the two most common reasons for not being able to edit a table in a Maximo application.

1. In the Work Order Tracking application, on the Work Order tab, the linear assets table is read-only unless you have installed the license key / Product Enabler for Linear.
2. In the same application on the Logs tab, the Work Log table will appear read-only in Application Designer because it is "included" from the LIBRARY "System XML". To edit it, you will need to export that System XML, edit it by hand in a text editor, and import it back. But be careful editing things in System XMLs because they are often used in many places in Maximo, not just in one place.

Comment: Asset Aplication.
Can't ediet History subtab's columns

Comment: Deleting / erasing "readonly" like that, and importing the changed XML, of course, will affect whether you can edit the data in the application, not whether you can edit the title in Application Designer. Instead, you need to add a `label="Machine Status"` attribute to your `<tablecol>` tag in the XML and import it.

Comment: But in this case title will be changed also in first app from which I get dublicate.

Comment: Yes, it will.

If that is not desirable, you can copy the table out of the Library over top of the reference to it in the Assets (Tr) app, or you can duplicate the table in the Library, give the duplicate a new id, and then change Assets (Tr) to reference your new table in the Library instead of the original one.

Comment: Thank you! Worked as I needed!